# CQRS Design Pattern Updates

Tags: database, design-patterns, cqrs

I was looking to implement CQRS pattern.  For the process of updating the read database, is it best to use a windows service, or to update the view at the time of creating a new record in the update database?  Is it best to use triggers, or some other process?  I've seen a couple of approaches and haven't made up my mind what is the best approach to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of the CQRS in your system?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I love to use messaging to solve these kind of problems.

You commands result in events when they are processed and if you use messaging to publish the events one or more downstream read services can subscribe to the events and process them to update the read models.

The reason why messaging is nice in this case is that it allows you to decouple the write and read side from each other. Also, it allows you to easily have several subscribers if you find a need for it. Additionally, messaging using a persistent queuing system like MSMQ enables retrying of failed messages. It also means that you can take a read model offline (for updates etc) and when it comes back up it can then process all the events in the queue.

I'm no friend of Triggers in relational databases, but I imagine the must be pretty hard to test. And triggers would introduce routing logic where it doesn't belong. Could it be also that if the trigger action fails, the entire write transaction rolls back? Triggers is probably the least beneficial solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how tolerant your application must be with regards to eventual consistency.

If your app has no problem with read data being 5 minutes old, there's no need to denormalize upon every write data change. In that case, a background service that kicks in every n minutes or that kicks in only when the CPU consumption is below a certain threshold, for instance, can be a good solution.

If, on the other hand, your app is time-sensitive, such as in the case of frequently changing statuses, machine monitoring, stock exchange data etc., then you will want to keep the lag as low as possible and denormalize on the spot -- that is, in-process or at least in real-time. So in this case you may choose to run the denormalizers in a constantly-running process or to add them to the chain of event handlers straight in your code.

Your call.